# Queuing multi-tenant application in Laravel

Tags: queue, laravel-5.1, multi-tenant, job-scheduling

I have a multi-tenant application built in Laravel 5.1. It uses one main database connection for storing users, roles, permissions, as well as jobs and failed_jobs. Additionally, every user has his own database.

I use a Job class for sending mail, and when it is executed, the following exception occurs:

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

The class uses tables from two db connections (the main connection, and the one associated with the current user).

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was easy. For anyone who is interested, I totally forgot to set the database in the second connection.

In fact, the `database` field in the second db connection is dynamically filled, depending on the authenticated user. So, each time the job class is executed, there should be initialization of the `database` field:

```
Config::set('database.connections.second_connection.database', 'user_' . $user_id);
// $user_id is in fact auth()->user()->id, passed as parameter
```

That solves the problem.

Comment: Hey @icemanblas, I came across similar issue where i am trying to switch between databases depending on the tenant. i have implemented a similar solution but I what happens is the database connections are not switched in shorter intervals , I mean if tenant 1 had a job executed with its DB connected , withing few seconds another tenant pushes a job to same queue the database connection is still that of previous tenant even after setting default connection. any similar experience ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 I abandoned that project a while ago, but as far as I remember, we did not have that kind of problem, and we tested different flows and scenarios.

Comment: Ah its alright, actually i resolved that issue by using DB::purge(); :) it works perfectly smooth now. Thanks anyways :D

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i am facing same kind of issues where i have to change database in a laravel job. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Sure @mohit elaborate your issue or post it as a new question

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i have a multi tenant app where every client have their own database but the code remains same for all. Now i want to create job that will execute some tasks for all the clients. Now i want to switch the database ii tried to change the database by updating default connection but its not working

Comment: @mohit please share the code so that i get a clear picture and also explain which multi tenant package are you using

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i am not using any package. Right now i am changing database by middlewares. The only issue is with jobs. Since there won't be any HTTP call so i cannot switch the database by middlwares.

Comment: What is your database division logic ? based on domain or any other ?  If it is domain based how will you know you which database to select do you have a master database to reference ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i have a master database with all of of my all client's domain and database details. When the application will load it will check for the database against that subdomain and it will connect that db. Now the issue is with the Job since there is no http requests so i cant change the db according to the subdomain. I am stuck at that issue.

Comment: @mohit What i have done is i am passing the database configuration to the Job while pushing it to the queue. Check this code sample https://pastebin.com/X7rDqHL6 hope this helps you.

Comment: @BlackBurn027 i got it working. The Config facade was not included properly in my code